# ImportError: No module named tensorflow, but tensorflow does exist

Tags: python, linux

I installed tensorflow with virtualenv on linux. There is a tensorflow package under sitepackage folder, but when I run the demo downloaded from Github, it shows:

```
(tensorflow) idc@idc-Hi-Fi-Z77X:~/tensorflow$ sudo python CNN_sentence_tensorflow-master/sentence_classfier_with_tensorflow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_sentence_tensorflowmaster/sentence_classfier_with_tensorflow.py", line 13, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

I do this at interface. It's ok:

```
(tensorflow) idc@idc-Hi-Fi-Z77X:~/tensorflow/multi-class-text-classification-cnn-master$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sudo python` basically means `run python` as some other user (root by default). That user may have a different set of environment variables, including `$PATH`.

Some of linux distributions use older Python version for root user,like `centos`.Have a look at the outputs of `which python` and `sudo which python`, you'll see they might be different.

```
[~]$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
[~]$ sudo which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Maybe you don't need to use `sudo`,or you can set permissions to all files and folders by using `chmod -R 755 /folder`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: OK, but I still have a question that is what if I do need the permission to write some files. How can I get the permission that this user doesn't have?

Answer (score 1):

you are using `sudo python CNN_sentence_tensorflow-master/sentence_classfier_with_tensorflow.py`

if you use `sudo` i think it will use your main python version not the one in your virtualenv